# Can I change what the button on my Bluetooth headset does?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, headphones

I have several Bluetooth headsets that have a function button in addition to volume up and volume down buttons.

How can I specify – or even determine – what the effects are of pushing that button?

While such a headset is connected to my iPhone XS, pressing the function button once often toggles pause/play on the current music player app (even if in the background).  If I double-click the button ... weirdness.  E.g., it might initiate a phone call to the last person I called.

Comment: I think the way you've currently written this question borders on being off-topic.  If the headset are Apple products, you can look in the iPhone's bluetooth settings to see what the buttons do.  If they're not Apple products, then you'll need to contact the maker of that headset to determine how it's been programmed.

Comment: @fsb: The headset maker doesn't get to decide what iOS does when it receives a Bluetooth "button 3" signal.

Comment: Yes, they do.  Apple devices support the "Audio/Video Remote Control Profile" and meet the requirements of the "Bluetooth Audio/Video Remote Control Profile Specification", Version 1.4.  These are agreed-upon commands. Apple provides some options to view/change what happens when it receives a command but only for their devices.  3rd-party makers can supply their own software to do the same thing so if you have this type of headset you should contact the maker.

Comment: @fsb: Looks like you're right, and that would be a great answer!